# Updating MangoSlick progress bar after it has been created

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I was assigned to integrate MangoSlick theme to our current admin panel,
Its a jQuery, Slick(?) and Responsive template.

First, let me explain how the API goes

In the documentation, it only says this is the only way

```
data-[options]=[value]
```

Example:
If I wanna make a progress bar

I can use this format

```
<div class="progress">
            <div class="bar" data-title="[title]" data-value="[value]" data-max="[max]" data-format="[format string]"></div>
</div>
```

so filling-in values

```
<div class="progress">
        <div class="bar" data-title="Space" data-value="1285" data-max="5120" data-format="0,0 MB"></div>
</div>
```

I will have this as output

[image]

Now, the main question is when I use jQuery attr() to change the attribute values for data-title, data-max, data-value and data-format.

Why is it not working?

```
<script>
    var jq = $.noConflict();
    jq(document).ready(function(){
      jq('#bokz').attr("data-title", "No Space");
    });
</script>
```

Using the script above and inspect element in chrome the values are changed

[image]

but not in the progressbar

[image]

Some of you may have some ideas on this?

Any help/suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes of the general format `data-foo="bar"` are read and written by jQuery with the `.data()` method.

So you can try this :

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
  jq('#bokz').data("title", "No Space");
});
```

which may work, though it probably depends on when the `.data()` method is called.

I would guess that `.data("title", "No Space")` will only work before the progress bar is initialized.

To set it after it is initialized, I would expect you need to invoke some method directly on the progress bar's API. If so, then you will need to look through the widget's documentation to find the appropriate method, eg `.setTitle(bar)` or `.progressBar('setTitle', bar)`.

Comment: Hi @Beetroot-Beetroot
I was hoping that '.data()' would do the trick as many of other widgets are using the same format(?)

Comment: Unfortunately, its not working as it should be, so I used the Library from jqueryui.com and it works fine, but only for the '.progressbar()'
 I still need to look for a way to insert data-values into these elements for other widget types like Charts, Tables and other stuffs
The documentation is full of samples but all of them are static, no Dynamic ones which is what I'm after
Thanks for the idea about '.data()' , I really didn't know that

Comment: To interact with a widget after it has been initialized, you need to understand its methods and events, which are documented in the API documentation. For example, the jQ-UI Progressbar has `destroy()`, `disable()`, `enable()`, `option()`, `value()`, `widget()` methods and `change`, `create`, `complete` events. The documentation describes each in detail, complete with sample code. Documentation for non-jQ-UI widgits (and other types of plugin) is similar, though not always as good.

Comment: yes, I fully understand that beetroot, I get what you are trying to say, and you're totaly correct.
the thing is I have no idea what libraries these widgets are using, they are only documented to be used in `data-[option]=[value]` format
I'm still digging up the JS libraries, hopefully I can hack into it

So that being said, I will mark your answer as the correct one, since I am satisfied with it. thanks for the help!

Comment: @bonesnatch, sorry I didn't mean to lecture you on stuff you already know. It shouldn't be too hard to track down the js libraries. I would start with "view source" in the browser. That's a whole lot easier than rummaging around in the bowels of server-side MVC source.